# Find document with its surroundings in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo collection with documents like below:

```
{
  _id: [ObjectId]
  writeDate: [DateTime]
  publishDate: [DateTime]
  ...
}
```

I usually display list of such documents sorting by `publishDate` first and then on `writeDate`.

Now when I get given document `_id` I need to fetch list containing: 2 previous documents, this document and 2 next documents. So it should look like as follows:

```
[1,2,4,3,6,7,8,5,9,0]
```

if given id is 6 I should get

```
[4,3,6,7,8]
```

and if id is 4 I should get

```
[1,2,4,3,6]
```

The thing is that publish dates may be the same (then I additionally sort by `writeDate`), so I suppose I can't just order using `$gte` and `$lte` with given document's date. Also `_id` are not guaranteed to be in order.

Do you have any clues on how to do this?

Comment: There's something I fail to understand in your question: you say that you can't sort based by date, since multiple documents may share the same date. If there is no sort order, there is no such thing as the next two and previous two documents. Or are you sorting your documents by `_id`?

Comment: Edited my question. I meant `publishDate` can be the same on several documents so I have orderAsc(publishDate) and orderAsc(writeDate).

Comment: Can there be duplicate publish and write dates?

Comment: In theory yes, but then sort order is undefined and I suppose it's ok. Those are extremely rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in one query, but you will have to use three instead:

```
// current
r = db.so.findOne( { _id: 6 } );

// previous 2
db.so
    .find( { publishDate: { $lte: r.publishDate }, _id: { $ne: 6 } )
    .sort( { publishDate: -1 } )
    .limit( 2 );

// next 2
db.so
    .find( { publishDate: { $gte: r.publishDate }, _id: { $ne: 6 } )
    .sort( { publishDate: 1 } )
    .limit( 2 );
```